# virtualenv can't execute on my system?

Tags: virtualenv, anaconda

I'm trying to create a virtual environment to deploy a Flask app. However, when I try to create a virtual environment using virtualenv, I get this error:

> `Using base prefix '//anaconda'
>   New python executable in /Users/sydney/Desktop/ptproject/venv/bin/python
>   ERROR: The executable /Users/sydney/Desktop/ptproject/venv/bin/python is not functioning
>   ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/sydney/Desktop/ptproject' (should be '/Users/sydney/Desktop/ptproject/venv')
>   ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable`

I think that I installed virtualenv using conda. When I use `which virtualenv`, I get this

> `//anaconda/bin/virtualenv`

Is this an incorrect location for virtualenv? I can't  figure out what else the problem would be. I don't understand the error log at all.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `virtualenv` just doesn't work correctly with `conda`.  For example:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367

(A workaround is proposed at the end of that thread, but it looks like you may be seeing a slightly different error, so maybe it won't work for you.)

Instead of deploying your app with `virtualenv`, why not just use a proper conda environment?  Conda environments are more general (and powerful) than those provided by `virtualenv`.

For example, to create a new environment with python-2.7 and flask in it:

```
conda create -n my-new-env flask python=2.7
```

Comment: Well I am trying to deploy my app on pythoneverywhere, and it asks me for a virtualenv path. Is there a way to deploy an app using a conda environment so that it can be hosted on something like pythoneverywhere (or maybe heroku)?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with pythoneverywhere or heroku.  Googling for "heroku conda" turns up some interesting pages, but I'm not in a position to judge their quality.  Maybe you could try asking for advice on the anaconda mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda